# Php 5 to php 7 session pb

Tags: php, session

Ubuntu is now in php7 and I have a pb with my application and I don't know how to resolve this.

Could you help me. Where  can change this element?

Thank you.

The errors

```
Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session callback expects true/false return value in /home/www//boutique/includes/functions/sessions.php on line 153

Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed. ID: user (path: /tmp/) in /home/www//boutique/includes/functions/sessions.php on line 153
```

the line 153

```
function osc_session_recreate() {
    global $SID;

      $old_id = session_id();

      session_regenerate_id(true); // =========> line 153

      if (!empty($SID)) {
        $SID = session_name() . '=' . session_id();
      }

    WhosOnline::WhosOnlineUpdateSessionId($old_id, session_id());

  }
```

My function
      use OM\HTTP;
      use Sites\Shop\WhosOnline;
      use OM\Registry;
      use OM\OSCOM;

```
  if (STORE_SESSIONS == 'mysql') {

    function _sess_open($save_path, $session_name) {
      return true;
    }

    function _sess_close() {
      return true;
    }

    function _sess_read($key) {
      $OSCOM_PDO = Registry::get('Db');    

      $Qsession = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('select value
                                       from :table_sessions 
                                       where sesskey = :sesskey
                                      ');
      $Qsession->bindValue(':sesskey', $key);
      $Qsession->execute();

      if ($Qsession->fetch() !== false) {
        return $Qsession->value('value');
      } else {
        return '';
      }

    }

    function _sess_write($key, $value) {

      $OSCOM_PDO = Registry::get('Db');
      $OSCOM_Mail = Registry::get('Mail');

      $Qcheck = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('select 1
                                    from :table_sessions
                                    where sesskey = :sesskey
                                   ');
      $Qcheck->bindValue(':sesskey', $key);
      $Qcheck->execute();      


      if (strlen($value) > 65535) {
// administrator email
        $email_subject = 'Error Mysql on ' . STORE_NAME;
        $message = 'Error Mysql, Data truncated for column value in last session and not saved for keeping stability. there are certainly too many items in your cart <br /><br />Please contact your administrator<br /><br />ClicShopping system has also send an email at your administrator';
        $name = STORE_NAME;
        $email_address = STORE_OWNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        $OSCOM_Mail->oscMail(STORE_NAME, STORE_OWNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, $email_subject, $message, $name, $email_address, '');

        osc_db_error("SQL SESSION ERROR", "<p>Warning: #1265, #1046 Data truncated for column 'value' in last session and not saved for keeping stability", strlen(osc_db_input($value)) . " characters would be truncated to 65535" . '</p><p><font color="#ff0000">Sorry for the inconvenience but ' . STORE_NAME . ' online shopping system has reached its limit of. Probably too many items in cart. We recommend that you remove some products from the basket, and instead do one more after this order.</font></p><br /><p>&nbsp;<a href="' . OSCOM::link('index.php', 'Cart', 'SSL') . '">' . IMAGE_BUTTON_CONTINUE . '</a><br /><br />&nbsp;<a href="' . OSCOM::link('index.php','Info&Contact', 'SSL') . '">' . 'Contact' . '</a></p>' );
      }

      if ($Qcheck->fetch() !== false) {
        return $OSCOM_PDO->save('sessions', ['expiry' => time(), 
                                            'value' => $value
                                            ],
                                            ['sesskey' => $key]

                                );

      } else {

        return $OSCOM_PDO->save('sessions', ['sesskey' => $key, 
                                            'expiry' => time(), 
                                            'value' => $value]
                                            );
      }

    }

    function _sess_destroy($key) {
      $OSCOM_PDO = Registry::get('Db');

      return $OSCOM_PDO->delete('sessions', ['sesskey' => $key]);
    }

    function _sess_gc($maxlifetime) {
      $OSCOM_PDO = Registry::get('Db');

      $Qdel = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('delete
                                   from :table_sessions 
                                   where expiry < :expiry
                                   ');
      $Qdel->bindValue(':expiry', time() - $maxlifetime);
      $Qdel->execute();

      return $Qdel->rowCount();
    }

    session_set_save_handler('_sess_open', '_sess_close', '_sess_read', '_sess_write', '_sess_destroy', '_sess_gc');
  }

  function osc_session_start() {

    $sane_session_id = true;

    if ( isset($_GET[session_name()]) ) {
      if ( (SESSION_FORCE_COOKIE_USE == 'True') || (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,-]+$/', $_GET[session_name()]) == false) ) {
        unset($_GET[session_name()]);

        $sane_session_id = false;
      }
    }

    if ( isset($_POST[session_name()]) ) {
      if ( (SESSION_FORCE_COOKIE_USE == 'True') || (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,-]+$/', $_POST[session_name()]) == false) ) {
        unset($_POST[session_name()]);

        $sane_session_id = false;
      }
    }

    if ( isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) ) {
      if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,-]+$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()]) == false ) {
        $session_data = session_get_cookie_params();

        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, $session_data['path'], $session_data['domain']);
        unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);

        $sane_session_id = false;
      }
    }

    if ($sane_session_id == false) {
      OSCOM::redirect('index.php', '', 'SSL', false);
    }

// php7 pb
//   register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

    return session_start();
  }

  function osc_session_recreate() {
    global $SID;

      $old_id = session_id();

      session_regenerate_id(true);

      if (!empty($SID)) {
        $SID = session_name() . '=' . session_id();
      }

    WhosOnline::WhosOnlineUpdateSessionId($old_id, session_id());

  }
```